# AdWords Script Pulling Campaign Data Report

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-ads-api

I am trying to pull yesterdays total campaign spend and clicks into my Google Sheets, but my current setup returns "undefined" for my "Clicks" column and 0 for my "TotalCost" column. When I pull this data at the account level my setup is fine, but when I switch to the campaign level I run into these issues. Thoughts on where I am incorrectly pulling the data?

```
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/tttttt").getActiveSheet();
  var emptyRow = findEmptyRow(sheet);

  var yesterday = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000));

  var range = sheet.getRange(emptyRow + 1, 1, 1, 10);

  var row = range.getValues();
  row[0][0] = yesterday;

  var stats = AdWordsApp.report('SELECT CampaignName, ExternalCustomerId, TotalCost, Amount, BiddingStrategyId, Impressions ' +
    'FROM CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT DURING YESTERDAY'

    )
    .rows()
    .next();
  row[0][1] = stats["Clicks"];
  row[0][2] = stats["TotalCost"];


  range.setValues(row);
}

function findEmptyRow(sheet) {
  var dates = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 365, 1).getValues();
  for (var emptyDate = 0; emptyDate < dates.length; emptyDate ++) {
    if (dates[emptyDate][0].length == 0) {
      return emptyDate;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clicks: you didn't add 'Clicks' field to the report.
TotalCost: that field does not exists, check the available fields in Adwords page: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/campaign-performance-report